# Limit without l'Hospital for a function with denominator $x$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have to find the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sin x+\cos x-2}x$$ without using L'Hospital. I know I have to find $-1$, indicated by plotting the graph of the function and by implementing the L'Hospital Rule. However, when I try more traditional approaches such as multiplying/dividing with the conjugate, factorising, etc,I hit a brick wall. Any suggestions?

Comment: Split it up as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-1}{x}-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x}$

Comment: Can you use $\sqrt{1+y}\approx1+\frac12y$ and $\cos y=1-\frac12y^2$?

Comment: You could use the fact that $-2 < -\sin{x}+\cos{x}<2$ and the squeze theorem.

Comment: @Odestheory12: You won't be able to conclude with your hint.

Comment: @Surb Right oh, i misread the question, I thought he was asking about existence. I am sorry.

Comment: @Andrei Isn't that basically using l'Hopital, only with different notation?

Comment: @Arthur it might be for the square root. For the trigonometric function it depends on how you define the function. The modern way of defining sine and cosine is through series.

Comment: @StinkingBishop you are correct. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrei Regardless of definitions, what you propose is to look at the value and first derivatives at $0$ to come to an answer. That's exactly what l'Hopital is.

Comment: You can use the Taylor expansion at $x=0$: $\sqrt{1+x^2}=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3),~\sin(x)=x+O(x^3),~\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$, which immediately yields the result.

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera Isn't that basically using l'Hopital, only with different notation?

Comment: It is not in my view, but in both you use derivatives to obtain the result.

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera In both you differentiate the numerator and the denominator once, then compare the values of those first derivatives. And if they are still both $0$, you differentiate one more time. Sounds like it's the same thing to me. Only difference is notation, and a factor of $\frac{n!}{n!}$.

Comment: @Arthur definitely not. You make the Taylor series only of non-polynomial terms, i.e. here only in the numerator. You transform everything to polynomials and then it is straightforward.

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera I would have used it if the student knew it and had been taught to them :P